# Galois group of the polynomial $(X^2+1)(X^2 +X +1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, galois-theory

I'm not sure if what I did is right and I would appreciate if someone could check if my steps are correct. The polynomial
$X^5+X^3-X^2-1$ factors over $\Bbb Q$ as $$(X-1)(X^2 +1)(X^2+X+1),$$ and I need to find out its splitting field.

After I calculated the roots I thought the field extension would be
$Q(\sqrt 3,i)$ because the roots are $\pm i $ and $\frac{1\pm i\sqrt3}{2}$.

Now first of all I'm not sure if I can just ''pretend'' as if my roots are $\pm i $ and $\frac{\pm  i\sqrt3}{2}$ where I check what my automorphism do on them because $\frac{1}{2}$  is a rational number so my automorphism ignores it. If it is possible, is it true that my Galois group is isomorphic to $Z/2Z \times Z/2Z$ then?

And if I consider the polynomial over $F_5$ it can be reduced to $(X-1)(X-2)(X-3)(X^2+X+1)$, so its Galois group is isomorphic to $Z/2Z$, since $(X^2+X+1)$ is irreducible, right?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, avoid the use of $*$ to denote multiplication. That's a common practice in programming languages, but this is a math forum. Use `\cdot` to get $\cdot$, `\times` to get $\times$ or plain juxtaposition (you did that in the body of the question, why didn't you do that in the title?)

Comment: Right in all your points. It is now only a matter of getting it written in a clear, correct way; for example, why **really** (meaning: how'd you justify or prove it) is your first Galois group $\;C_2\times C_2\;$ ?

Comment: I looked at what my automorphism do on my roots. So one automorphism ($\tau_1$) maps i to -i and is the identity on $\sqrt(3)$ and the other way around for my second automorphism ($\tau_2$). The third automorphism is then ($\tau_1\tau_2$) and they all have order 2.